# Como completar un número con ceros a la izquierda

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo tener un consecutivo con ceros a la izquierda?

He podido observar que en c#, cuando uno agrega ceros a la izquierda de una variable, no los toma en cuenta.

Lo que necesito es establecer un consecutivo de 10 dígitos de esta forma: `0000000000`, entonces que se vaya sumando de uno en uno pero de derecha a izquierda en secuencia, por ejemplo `0000000001`, `0000000002`, `000000003`, `0000000004` y así sucesivamente; de manera que después de 9 se pase de la siguiente forma `0000000010`, `0000000011`, `0000000012`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Puedes usar el metodo .ToString() con formato "D10", asi

```
int numero = 15;
//0000000015
var numeroFormato= numero.ToString("D10");
```

Adicionalmente te dejo el enlace de la documentación con los formatos, por si necesitas revisar alguno de los formatos adicionales [Formatos Numericos MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)