# Limitar la cantidad de espacios en una variable string y rellenar espacios en C#

Tags: c#

Necesito combinar 2 datos en un txt, limitar el 2do dato y reemplazar los espacios con 0. me explico.
Tengo un prefijo (**BCO**), una secuencia numérica y una longitud(**8**).

El prefijo debe de juntarse con la secuencia numérica dejando 0 en el medio e ir reemplazando a medida de que se agreguen las decenas, centenas, etc.

Combinado debe de dar algo como esto `BCO00000001`

Comment: @Arriel esta interesante, lo voy a intentar y te aviso

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar `PadLeft(int,char)`, donde el primer argumento es la cantidad de  caracteres y el segundo es el carácter de relleno que aplicará a la izquierda cuando falten para cumplir el largo dado en el primer argumento.

Ejemplo

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetCodigo("BC0", 1));        //BC000000001
    Console.WriteLine(GetCodigo("ACF", 1234));     //ACF00001234
    Console.WriteLine(GetCodigo("YUS", 12345678)); //YUS12345678
}

public static string GetCodigo(string prefix, int num)
{
    return $"{prefix}{num.ToString().PadLeft(8,'0')}";
}
```

Comment: Voté negativamente la respuesta porque... ya sabemos por qué...

Comment: Hola @Arriel, yo puedo suponer el motivo, pero para estar seguro puedes clarificarlo???

Comment: Creo que no te equivocarías, sin embargo con gusto lo aclararé. [La razón subyacente es esta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/155807); pero en este caso considero más formativo penalizar la respuesta, para desmotivar a los usuarios con mayor *tenure* a contestar preguntas que no demuestran esmero en su solución. Debo dar crédito que el requerimiento es claro, sin embargo, el esfuerzo es nulo. Es la responsabilidad de la comunidad mantener la calidad de las preguntas, y esto se logra, entre otras maneras, no respondiendo aquellas sin esfuerzo por su resolución... Y con votos negativos.

Comment: @Arriel Ok, agradezco la gentileza de explicarme tus razones. Aunque discrepo de ellas. Si para responder hubiera sido necesario aplicar un algoritmo podría estar un poco más de acuerdo con tu punto, pero en este caso el fondo del asunto está en el desconocimiento de la función `PadLeft`, es como si la pregunta hubiera sido *¿Como transformar el string "123" en entero?*, la respuesta es `int.Parse`, la pregunta no requiere código y no sé como se podría evaluar el esfuerzo en la pregunta para ese caso (ni este)

Comment: Entonces para mi esta es una pregunta valida, el OP no sabe que existe una función que resuelve el problema, por lo que no sabe ni siquiera como buscar la solución. Y teniendo en cuenta que no tiene votos negativos ni votos de cierres, me parece que cualquiera puede responderla, por lo que creo que tu voto de castigo no aplica.

Comment: Y por último, ya desde mi caso particular te aviso que no me desmotiva para nada. Con un voto positivo que obtenga elimino 5 negativos. Como no es juego suma cero, ningún voto negativo hará que me desmotive en responder tanto como pueda.

Comment: Aprecio tu esmero en defender tu postura. Creo que tu pregunta ejemplo *¿Cómo transformar el string "123" en entero?* es igual de mala, pues cinco minutos buscando en google y revisar documentación lo responden. Buscar *"operaciones con cadenas c#"*, *"rellenar con ceros c#"*, dan resultados útiles, incluyendo preguntas [dentro de este mismo sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/202544/como-completar-un-n%C3%BAmero-con-ceros-a-la-izquierda), que OP pudo haber leído para resolver su problema. Está bien que no te desmotive, imagino que has ayudado mucho aquí; mas no con esta respuesta.

Comment: @Arriel Bueno, claramente no estamos de acuerdo. Gracias nuevamente por darte el tiempo de explicarme tu postura (no era tu obligación hacerlo).  Saludos

Comment: Claro. Un gusto y siempre a la orden :)